# Drawing a single bar in vertical bar chart with three different values

Tags: android

Hi in one of my Android projects, I need to show a bar graph where each bar should be shown with three different colors/values(Stacked bar charts). Could some one help me out in implementing these.

Comment: You can get help from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23102302/1777090)

Comment: Easily achieved with most of the android libraries you have out there to implement charts. You can check [williamchart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart).